# How to Cancel Automatic deletion of Cpanel accounts on expiry by WHMCS

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting, whmcs

My WHMCS Installation seems to be deleting my cpanel accounts once their end of term is reached, even when I have already initiated a renewal for the cpanel account. How can I change these settings in WHMCS? its really causing a lot of headache epecially when my clients renew their accounts only to discover that their cpanel account is blank, all files, emails and dbs gone.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Goto - Setup Menu - > Automation Settings

Enable Termination  ( You can disable this option if you dont want to terminate automatically)

Ticking this option will terminate the clients’ package (remove it from the server) according to the setting below.
Termination Days

Once the product/service is this many days overdue the clients’ account will be terminated.

http://docs.whmcs.com/Automation_Settings

Comment: Thanks, though i had already set this option, but i set no. of days to 45 days, yet, once clients' accounts expires, the account is deleted on the very same day.